# Help identifying this Pokemon-like character

Tags: game-identification

I received a mixed bag of Pokemon figurines with varying degrees of accuracy with regards to their colour and appendages. All but one of them I have been able to identify, and my conclusion is that while it looks like a pokemon, I don't think it is.

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Is someone able to identify the character? As it was in a mixed bag of Pokemon characters, I figure the chances are that the factory produced characters from a number of game franchises, and this one got mixed in. I'm also open to the fact that it might be a Pokemon and I have a gap in my knowledge.

Here's an example of the pokemon figurines received at the same time, in which this mystery figure was found:

[image: eBay]

Comment: All we can tell you it's that not a Pokémon. Asking for anything more would be off-topic here, as there's nothing that makes this figure related to video games.

Comment: Do you have a larger and/or higher quality image of the Pokemon figurines? I do wonder if your toy is indeed meant to be a Pokemon but is poorly designed. The reason I speculate this is that the figure in the bottom corner is poorly designed - it appears to be intentioned to be Spearow, but it has many differences. I can't clearly tell if that figurine is one of those in your picture due to the Pokemon's small size, but I might with a larger picture.

Answer (score 2):

That's either a fake Pokemon figurine due to it not looking like any Pokemon I've seen, OR it's a figurine for something else entirely.

My long shot guess (if it is a Pokemon figurine) is it's a poorly made Excadrill, specifically the shiny variant. [image]

but again, it's a long shot and really the closest thing I can think of.